# `git` get metrics on how often `rerere` resolutions are used

Tags: git, git-rerere

Does `git rerere` expose information about how frequently different conflicts are used? Or how frequently the feature is used overall?

---

`git` has the ability to remember resolutions to previous conflicts and apply them in the future (called [rerere](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rerere)).

I used this feature once a long time ago, but disabled it after it remembered and kept reapplying a merge conflict that I had resolved incorrectly.

These days I make much fewer mistakes when resolving conflicts, work with smaller commits, and rebase unshared work very frequently, so I'm trying `rerere` out again.

I'd like to be able to see how often it's being triggered.

---

The source code that implements this feature is [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/rerere.c).

Rerere has some neat stuff, like [garbage collection](https://github.com/git/git/blob/dadef801b365989099a9929e995589e455c51fed/rerere.c#L1195), which seems to limit how far into the future a recorded resolution can be applied? Or perhaps the lack-of-use deadline after which it will be lazily GC'd (similar to how `gc` works for ordinary git objects)?